# Use of the german prefix “eigen” in French (as in eigenvalue, eigenstrain, etc.)

Tags: usage, mathématiques, néologismes, science, allemand

In mathematics, physics, mechanics and the like, one encounters *eigen* as a prefix in *eigenvalues* and *eigenvectors*, as well as in *eigenstrain* and *eigenstress*. The word comes from German and means “own” or “intrinsic”. In the English scientific literature *eigen* is widely accepted and commonly employed.

Have the terms *eigenvecteur* and *eigenvaleurs* ever been used in French (even as neologisms)?
Is their use in French acceptable (university level and higher) nowadays (in place of the adjective *propre*; that is, "valeurs propres, vecteurs propres")?

In that case the diphthong *ei* should be pronounced as in German (aï) ? If its use isn't acceptable, what reasons could explain why *eigen* was not introduced in French?

Comment: In French, the word eigen is not in use as you can easily see. In English, we use it since the first translation of Hilbert, who introduced the term in German (cf. wikipedia: valeur propre, vecteur propre, espace propre). Wikipedia also says that Jordan introduced the French terminology: valeur propre.

Comment: @user66288 Comments should be used to ask for clarifications or suggest improvements. Your comment looks like an answer so would benefit to be posted as such. (As a bonus, changing your nickname from user<somenumber> to something more distinctive would be nice...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The academic translation of eigenvalue is

```
valeur propre
```

This is what you will most likely find in most of the academic documents.

[Vecteur propre for eigenvector merci @Regis Portalez]

Comment: Vecteur propre for eigenvector